# mysql data sorting according to the time interval

Tags: c#, mysql

In my MySQL data base table there are data in each 10 minutes intervals ,ex
//time format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

```
Time              | value

2012-03-02 1:10:00|2
2012-03-02 1:20:00|5
.
2012-03-02 2:00:00|3
```

The user can select a starting time, end time and the time interval(10 minutes,30 , 1hr,1 day) ,
ex if user select start time

:2012-03-02 1:15:00 , end time 2012-03-02 2:10:00 and interval as 10 minutes then result

```
Time              | value.

2012-03-02 1:15:00|2 
2012-03-02 1:25:00|5
.
2012-03-02 2:05:00|3
```

Value is the last data in the time interval,(ex data value of 15th would be the value of 10th minute)

What i do now is i get the whole set of data with in the time period without considering about the time interval and after that manipulate the data set manually(in my program) to get the result according to the user selected time interval, 
time interval means :10 mints,30 mints, 1hr, 1 day

My c# program becomes slow because there are lots of iterations, is their any way i can query the data base directly and to get the data at once, your comments are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your time intervals as a value, You can avoid all these problem by storing time intervals as two `DateTime` fields representing the starting and ending interval, like this:

- `UserId`.
- `StartingInterval`: DateTime.
- `EndingInterval`: DateTime.

Then you can get the time interval by subtracting the two `datetime` fields and for the set of data that fall into a set of interval by using the `BETWEEN` the two fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that MGA's answer makes sense, since you aren't storing intervals, you are storing events - and each event is associated with one time, not two.

I can't quite understand the inputs to your query, since if the user gives you a start time and end time, the interval is already set, isn't it? I think you only need the interval if one of the times is set (in other words, you need "2012 03 02 10:00:00" and "1 hour" OR "2012 03 02 10:00:00" and "2012 03 02 10:10:00").

Let's assume that if the user gives you one date and interval your program can translate that into a start time and an end time, so your query is going to get two input parameters: start_time and end_time.

Here's a query that works (testing with command line temp variables):

```
SELECT value FROM mytable
WHERE `Time` >= @start_time
AND `Time` <= @end_time
ORDER by `Time` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You'll have to handle the case where nothing is returned in your program, of course.